# Performance comparison: Mapping a LiveData value vs Flow value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

Currently, I am experimenting a bit with livedata and flow in android. What I stumbeld upon is, whether there are big performance differences when it comes to mapping a livedata value and a flow value because livedata mapping is performed in the main ui thread:

```
/**
 * Returns a [LiveData] mapped from `this` LiveData by applying [transform] to each value set on
 * `this` LiveData.
 *
 * This method is analogous to [io.reactivex.Observable.map].
 *
 * [transform] will be executed on the main thread.
 *
 * [...]
 **/
public inline fun <X, Y> LiveData<X>.map(crossinline transform: (X) -> Y): LiveData<Y> =
    Transformations.map(this) { transform(it) }
```

Now comes the trickery part: Let's assume we have a livedata value we want to map. Since mapping is performaned in the ui-thread, we convert the livedata value to a flow value:

```
public fun <T> LiveData<T>.asFlow(): Flow<T> = flow {
    val channel = Channel<T>(Channel.CONFLATED)
    val observer = Observer<T> {
        channel.offer(it)
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
        observeForever(observer)
    }
    try {
        for (value in channel) {
            emit(value)
        }
    } finally {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
            removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

After converting the livedata observer to a flow, we map the values successfully in another thread (Dispatchers.IO). But now we don't need a flow for the ui, so we convert it back to a livedata value:

```
@JvmOverloads
public fun <T> Flow<T>.asLiveData(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    timeoutInMs: Long = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
): LiveData<T> = liveData(context, timeoutInMs) {
    collect {
        emit(it)
    }
}
```

Now the questions:

1. Does mapping a livedata value has big performance impact in comparison to mapping a flow value
2. Does converting a livedata value to a flow value and then converting it back to livedata introduce any overhead and or performance issues? If yes, would it be better to directly map the livedata value?

A mapping example would be:

```
fun LiveData<WorkInfo>.collectStatus(): LiveData<Status<Unit>> = map { workInfo ->
    when(workInfo.state) {
        WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED -> Status.loading()

        WorkInfo.State.RUNNING -> Status.loading()

        WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> Status.success(Unit)

        WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED -> Status.failed("Workmanager blocked")

        WorkInfo.State.FAILED -> Status.failed("Workmanager failed")

        WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED -> Status.failed("Workmanager cancelled")
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by performance. There's miniscule extra overhead on top of the same work for the thread switching. But doing work off the main thread makes the UI animations smoother if they are ongoing while the work is being done, provided there's enough work being done to be perceptible. I don't think there's any significant difference in performance between LiveData and Flows, but it might be more convoluted code to map on a different thread when using pure LiveData.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But does `switchMap` in combination with  `liveData(context)` switch the thread?

Comment: Yes. `liveData` launches a coroutine that runs under the hood to publish to a LiveData.

Comment: Your example of a mapping transformation has the cost on the order of a few nanoseconds. Handing off a task from one thread to another has costs in the range of microseconds. So that's a factor of a thousand right there. Wrapping/unwrapping is insignificant by comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform mapping on a different thread, then you should use `LiveData.switchMap` with `liveData(context) { }`

```
livedata.switchMap { 
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO) { 
        emit(someValue)
    }
}
```

or get rid of LiveData and use Flow/StateFlow/SharedFlow/Channel everywhere

Comment: For my case above, is this context switching recommended? What would give the better performance: Directly mapping in the ui thread or first switching the context?

Comment: And why does your approach work? Because in the switchmap documentation it says, that transformation is still performed in the ui thread?